# Add and remove html element by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I add new `<tr>` after a clicked `<tr>`. On click of this `<tr>` and remove now created when click other `<tr>` (with repeat 1st scenario) by jQuery?

I tried like this, but it does not work:

```js
$("#test_table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).closest('tr').append('<tr><td>2.2</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/ *insert content to the end of each matched element* - so you're *inserting* a `tr` *into* another `tr`.   You need a different [insertion method](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)

Comment: Also note that `$(this).closest('tr')` will always be `$(this)` as the event is on the `tr` and `.closest` includes itself.

Answer (score 1):

Given your goal it seems that you want to replace the current `tr` with the new HTML snippet. To do that you just need to call `after()` to insert the new HTML, then `remove()` to clear the original `tr`:

```js
$("#test_table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).after('<tr><td>2.2</td></tr>').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, as the only effect of this is to change the text within the `td`, you can just call `text()` instead:

```js
$("#test_table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).find('td').text('2.2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```